# iOS. How to start storyboard from the beginning every time when application goes from background to an active state?

Tags: ios, storyboard, state

Title describes it all. Is it possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement the `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` method in your application. You can do whatever you'd normally do to set up the app's internal state. In fact, if you want the app to 'start over', you can probably move much of your code from `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to `-applicationDidBecomeActive:`. For example, you might use UIStoryboard's `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to reload your initial view controller and then set it as the window's root view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in your Info.plist (*Application does not run in background*)

Comment: This should be the recommended way of implementing exactly what the OP asked (i.e., the app behaves as if it does not support multitasking/backgrounding at all). I wonder why it does not work for the OP, and whether Apple has deprecated this functionality?

Comment: I just tried adding the key to my app's .plist. Display name is "Application does not run in background", actual key is `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` (right-click, choose "Show Raw Keys/Values"). It still works as of iOS 9.1.